# Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vercel

Everytime i build on Vercel it gives me this error on page load.

`"Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method"`

Anyone who can help me with this issue? Tt works fine on netlify but not on vercel.

It gives me the error with pages using "v-html"

But its a standard vue directive.

Here is an example of how i use the v-html:

````
    <div 
        v-if=" frontpage && frontpage.htmlText != null" 
        class="row container-wrap">
          <div
             class="seo-container col-lg-6"
             @click="openSeo"
             :class="{ 'is-open': seoOpen }">
                        <div
                            class="seo-container__content"
                            v-html="frontpage.htmlText"
                        />
          </div>
   </div>
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your last nested "div" with a non-self-closing tag:

```
<div class="seo-container__content" v-html="frontpage.htmlText"></div>
```

"Div" is a non-void HTML element and should have a closing tag.